# Multiple Hypothesis Testing in feature selection process

Tags: statistics, feature-selection, hypothesis-testing, chi-square-test

I am doing feature selection of features which are of binary nature i.e. each feature represents presence or absence of a substructure in a  molecule. And I have  a target variable of two classes. My first step was to check if my feature is associated with the target variable so I was using chi-square test for that.And later I check if the selected features have any correlation and remove that. So each feature is checked for association with target variable using chi square test. I am wondering if any correction methods are needed here in my case like bonferroni or false discovery rate. If yes what are the assumptions I should keep in mind. Really appreciate the help.

Comment: You're *removing* features that are correlated with the outcome?

Comment: I'm trying to check if features are associated with the target variable. For that, I'm using chi-square test hypothesis testing.

Comment: Could you please clarify what your criteria are for eliminating features?

Comment: So I have made two hypothesis; Null Hypothesis 0 : Feature & Target Variable are not dependent
● Alternate Hypothesis 1 : Feature & Target Variable are dependent
So for the feature with a p-value less than chosen
significance level α=0.05, the null hypothesis is rejected. And we say that the feature and target variable are associated. This is done for all features in a for loop.

Comment: So you keep the variable when the p-value is what?

Comment: As I said Dave, p value <=0.05, null hypothesis is rejected and the variable/ feature is kept.

Comment: what is the formula for computing "correlation" between selected features ? If you have "high" correlation between specific variables or features - why can not you remove them  before you take-up chi-squared test?

Comment: Are you using a (generalized) linear model? If so, are there interactions between the basic features? If not, are you using a model (such as a random forest or neural network) that looks for interactions without being told explicitly which ones matter? [Univariate screening is problematic for (generalized) linear models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/261900/247274), but the problem will be much worse if you use a method that investigates interactions. For instance, a neural network could solve the "X" [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/625461/247274) given *both* features, not one.

Answer (score 2):

In a basic statistical model like a logistic regression on the features, [this kind of univariate feature selection is problematic.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/261900/247274) Briefly, a candidate feature can be fairly unrelated to the outcome on its own but become quite important once another feature is considered. If you do univariate screening, you miss out on that kind of important feature.

If you use a more sophisticated machine learning model like a random forest or a neural network, even a logistic regression with feature interactions, then univariate screening is even more problematic. Consider the image below (taken from [another post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/621366/247274) of mine).

[image: red/blue X]

Jointly, the two features almost perfectly distinguish between red and blue. However, neither feature, alone, is at all correlated with the color. If you have interaction terms in a logistic regression or run a model like a random forest or neural network that will interact features as it sees fit, then you miss out on these being important features, even if their importance only happens in the interaction.

You can explicitly test for a correlation between the interaction and the outcome, which would reveal the interaction in this case to be extremely important, but then you're doing univariate screening (the interaction feature is, after all, a candidate feature), which is problematic as described above.

(I consider a chi-squared test to be a correlation-style measure, [due to the relationship between chi-squared testing and a score test in a logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/570582/247274), so I am content to use a bit of slang when I write "correlation".)